# Backup size doesn't seem to be correct

Tags: adb, backup, fastboot, linux, twrp

I installed `TWRP 3.1.0-0` (unofficial, from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xiaomi-redmi-3s/development/recovery-twrp-3-1-0-0-xiaomi-redmi-3s-t3585945)) on my Redmi 3S Prime and tried to make a Nandroid backup. I've never taken Nandroid backup before. I have a linux PC. On my PC, I installed `adb` and `fastoot` drivers and used took the backup by typing `adb backup --twrp` in the terminal. My phone showed that the backup size was `9757 MB` but the `backup.ab` file created was only `2.1 GB`. Where is the problem? Did I do anything wrong? By the way, I backed up the `boot`, `system` and `data (excl. storage)` partitions. Doing backups on internal storage works fine. So, what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a bug. I tested it on my device multiple times: in GUI mode backup is created fine, whereas console command give this fake.

I already created the [ticket](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/929) on their Github, but they don't read it, as it seems.

Comment: So, what should I do you suggest?

Comment: Nothing you can do here. Make backups via GUI until they fix the problem.